# Unable to create table with hibernate in maven eclipse with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am able to update the table using `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

But if I use create instead of `update` I get this error in tomcat console:

> Hibernate: drop table if exists USERS 2021-Feb-14 15:06:20 PM
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.access -
> HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess
> [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7381c5e]
> for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the
> Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection
> will be set into auto-commit mode. 2021-Feb-14 15:06:21 PM
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table USERS
> (ID integer not null auto_increment, NAME varchar(255), TOTAL integer,
> GOAL integer, primary key (ID)) type=MyISAM Hibernate: create table
> USERS (ID integer not null auto_increment, NAME varchar(255), TOTAL
> integer, GOAL integer, primary key (ID)) type=MyISAM 2021-Feb-14
> 15:06:21 PM [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO
> org.hibernate.orm.connections.access - HHH10001501: Connection
> obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess
> [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@24055e5]
> for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the
> Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection
> will be set into auto-commit mode. 2021-Feb-14 15:06:21 PM
> [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl -
> GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error
> executing DDL "create table USERS (ID integer not null auto_increment,
> NAME varchar(255), TOTAL integer, GOAL integer, primary key (ID))
> type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
> executing DDL "create table USERS (ID integer not null auto_increment,
> NAME varchar(255), TOTAL integer, GOAL integer, primary key (ID))
> type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439)
> [hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
> [hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]    at
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314)
> [hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line
> 1     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
> ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23] at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'studentdb.users' doesn't
> exist     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.jav

I am using java servlet to access database using JDBC, I need your help please.

Comment: Not sure what are these messages;org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Comment: at com.simplilearn.workshop.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:26) [classes/:?]      at com.simplilearn.workshop.InitHibernate.doGet(InitHibernate.java:36) [classes/:?] first one is class and second is servlet !!

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1

Comment: Finally I am able to fix the problem after fixing with this  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property> and before it was only MySQLDalect !!